# Importing mime .eml file to gmail API using the import function

Tags: python, gmail-api

I am a python developer and somewhat new to using Google's gMail API to import .eml files into a gMail account.

I've gotten all of the groundwork done getting my oAuth credentials working, etc.

However, I am stuck where I load in the data-file.  I need help loading the message data in to place in a variable..

How do I create the **message_data** variable reference - in the appropriate format - from my sample email file (which is stored in rfc822 format) that is on disk?

Assuming I have a file on disk at /path/to/file/sample.eml ... how do I load that to message_data in the proper format for the gMail API import call?

```
    ...
          # how do I properly load message_data from the rfc822 disk file?
          media = MediaIoBaseUpload(message_data, mimetype='message/rfc822')
          message_response = service.users().messages().import_(
              userId='me',
              fields='id',
              neverMarkSpam=True,
              processForCalendar=False,
              internalDateSource='dateHeader',
              media_body=media).execute(num_retries=2)

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to import an eml file using Gmail API.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Gmail API.
- You want to achieve this using google-api-python-client.

  - `service` in your script can be used for uploading the eml file.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification point:

- In this case, the method of "Users.messages: insert" is used.

#### Modified script:

Before you run the script, please set the filename with the path of the eml file.

```
eml_file = "###"  # Please set the filename with the path of the eml file.
user_id = "me"

f = open(eml_file, "r", encoding="utf-8")
eml = f.read()
f.close()
message_data = io.BytesIO(eml.encode('utf-8'))
media = MediaIoBaseUpload(message_data, mimetype='message/rfc822', resumable=True)
metadata = {'labelIds': ['INBOX']}
res = service.users().messages().insert(userId=user_id, body=metadata, media_body=media).execute()
print(res)
```

In above script, the following modules are also required.

```
import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload
```

#### Note:

- In above modified script, `{'labelIds': ['INBOX']}` is used as the metadata. In this case, the imported eml file can be seen at INBOX of Gmail. If you want to change this, please modify this.

#### Reference:

- [Users.messages: insert](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Can you import an eml file in Google Drive using Google Apps Script? Maybe calling Gmail.Users.Messagse.insert?